# Copying specific keys and values of a PHP multidimensional array into another array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => mail_failures_only
            [value] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => default_service_ttl
            [value] => 60
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => version
            [value] => 5.0.0.0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => process_all_jobs
            [value] => 1
        )
)
```

I want each value of "name" and each value of "value" to be converted to an associative array like this:

process_all_jobs =>1

How do a construct loop for this?

I tried something like this:

```
$system_config_array = array();
        if (is_array($configList)) {
            $keys = array_keys($configList);
            for($i = 0; $i < count($configList); $i++) {
                foreach($configList[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
                    echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";
                    if($key!='id')
                        $system_config_array[$value] = '';
                }
            }
       }
```

where $configList is the initial array.

Comment: see this : https://eval.in/1017632

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! It worked :) And I was using 2 for loops and an if and going mad ..

Comment: Please vote up my question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you :

```
$base = 'your array';
foreach ($base as $key => $value) {
    $data[$value['name']] = $value['value'];
}
print_r($data);
```

https://eval.in/1017632

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
$result = array_column($arr, "value", "name");
```

But this only works if the names are unique.

It doesn't answer your question to create a loop for it, but I belive array_column is a better tool for the job

Comment: Your array with value and names

Comment: Looping is not an optimal solution